# How to fix/replace shifter button?

Tags: automatic-transmission, shifting, gear-stick

The button from my automatic shifter just fell off one day. It looks like the plastic of the button's shaft has basically deteriorated.

I tried to glue it on and that lasted a couple of weeks before it fell out again.

Is there better way to reattach it? Do they just sell this part for me to replace in my own?

I've been just digging my thumb into the hole to engage the button.

Is there a hack for this? Can I just mold my own button by pressuring sculpy into the hole?

[image: shifter]

Comment: I think there's 2 decent answers on how you could go about this, what I would say is that if you do attempt a repair or fashion a button you need to be prepared for the eventuality that it could make the problem worse, as in jamming things. Know what you'll do in that eventuality.

Comment: I'd probably goto a junk yard and find one they are pretty easy to remove and basically fall out when removing the shift lever (depending on the car).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After more research, I actually found that you can just get [the replacement shift button on Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00BVPOC20).
I then searched for [an instructional video on YouTube](https://youtu.be/mZ5QvUlP4kw).

Answer (score 1):

Replacing the shifter is probably the only "proper" fix you can make.

If it were me, I would go down the route you suggested - make your own button. There is a really cool product called Sugru that would be ideal. It's essentially modelling clay that hardens into firm rubber in about 24 hours. It bonds really strongly, so will definitely stay put. Make sure you clean the area with something like rubbing alcohol first.

[sugru.com](https://sugru.com/)

Comment: I think I know what you're trying to say @raydowe, but I don't think it's come out right. Sugru doesn't bond to other surfaces really at least not as well as a glue, it hardens into the shape it's molded to. It needs something structural in the handle itself to wrap around or squeeze into if it's going to stay put.

Comment: @GdD I understand your skepticism, but you'd probably be surprised. I'd say it bonds better than most glues. It even works well on smooth, flat plastics as long as you have a decent amount of surface area.  I've used it on the outside of my motorcycle helmet, and even a quarter sized contact patch is enough to hold the weight of a GoPro. Most of the time, it needs to be cut off.

Answer (score 1):

Just guessing from the picture, that the plastic shaft is approximately 8mm in diameter. So, why not drill the chromed button and either tap a thread into it then glue a cut-down bolt or glue a hard plastic shaft into it?